# Setting pandas values based on range of times

Tags: pandas, time-series

I would like to set all values to some value (say 999) that occur within some time period (say 1 hour) of any value over some threshold (say 7). I have had some luck with wonky non-vectorized approaches, but there must be a better, pandastic way to do it...

An example is:

Setting up a random data frame :

```
hr_rng = pd.date_range(start='7/1/2014 00:00:00', end='7/1/2014 10:00:00', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(hr_rng, columns=['date_time'])
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date_time']),inplace=True)
df['val0']=np.random.randint(1, 10, df.shape[0])
```

A random output:

```
    date_time   val0
date_time       
2014-07-01 00:00:00     2014-07-01 00:00:00     4
2014-07-01 01:00:00     2014-07-01 01:00:00     8
2014-07-01 02:00:00     2014-07-01 02:00:00     4
2014-07-01 03:00:00     2014-07-01 03:00:00     7
2014-07-01 04:00:00     2014-07-01 04:00:00     2
2014-07-01 05:00:00     2014-07-01 05:00:00     4
2014-07-01 06:00:00     2014-07-01 06:00:00     4
2014-07-01 07:00:00     2014-07-01 07:00:00     9
2014-07-01 08:00:00     2014-07-01 08:00:00     1
2014-07-01 09:00:00     2014-07-01 09:00:00     9
2014-07-01 10:00:00     2014-07-01 10:00:00     5
```

What I would like to get back is this:

```
date_time   val0
date_time       
2014-07-01 00:00:00     2014-07-01 00:00:00     999
2014-07-01 01:00:00     2014-07-01 01:00:00     999
2014-07-01 02:00:00     2014-07-01 02:00:00     999
2014-07-01 03:00:00     2014-07-01 03:00:00     7
2014-07-01 04:00:00     2014-07-01 04:00:00     2
2014-07-01 05:00:00     2014-07-01 05:00:00     4
2014-07-01 06:00:00     2014-07-01 06:00:00     999
2014-07-01 07:00:00     2014-07-01 07:00:00     999
2014-07-01 08:00:00     2014-07-01 08:00:00     999
2014-07-01 09:00:00     2014-07-01 09:00:00     999
2014-07-01 10:00:00     2014-07-01 10:00:00     999
```

Another random example:

```
    date_time   val0
date_time       
2014-07-01 00:00:00     2014-07-01 00:00:00     5
2014-07-01 01:00:00     2014-07-01 01:00:00     6
2014-07-01 02:00:00     2014-07-01 02:00:00     3
2014-07-01 03:00:00     2014-07-01 03:00:00     2
2014-07-01 04:00:00     2014-07-01 04:00:00     9
2014-07-01 05:00:00     2014-07-01 05:00:00     7
2014-07-01 06:00:00     2014-07-01 06:00:00     6
2014-07-01 07:00:00     2014-07-01 07:00:00     8
2014-07-01 08:00:00     2014-07-01 08:00:00     6
2014-07-01 09:00:00     2014-07-01 09:00:00     7
2014-07-01 10:00:00     2014-07-01 10:00:00     3
```

Should become this:

```
date_time   val0
date_time       
2014-07-01 00:00:00     2014-07-01 00:00:00     5
2014-07-01 01:00:00     2014-07-01 01:00:00     6
2014-07-01 02:00:00     2014-07-01 02:00:00     3
2014-07-01 03:00:00     2014-07-01 03:00:00     999
2014-07-01 04:00:00     2014-07-01 04:00:00     999
2014-07-01 05:00:00     2014-07-01 05:00:00     999
2014-07-01 06:00:00     2014-07-01 06:00:00     999
2014-07-01 07:00:00     2014-07-01 07:00:00     999
2014-07-01 08:00:00     2014-07-01 08:00:00     999
2014-07-01 09:00:00     2014-07-01 09:00:00     999
2014-07-01 10:00:00     2014-07-01 10:00:00     999
```

Comment: Can you be more specific why is set all values without 3 rows? Where is set 7 threshold? Also is possible post your not vectorize solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, IIUC:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

hr_rng = pd.date_range(start='7/1/2014 00:00:00', 
                       end='7/1/2014 10:00:00', 
                       freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(hr_rng, columns=['date_time'])
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date_time']),inplace=True)
df['val0']=np.random.randint(1, 10, df.shape[0])
```

Now, update rows that are equal to or greater than the threshold.

```
threshold = 7

# initialize
df['test'] = df['val0']

mask = df['val0'] >= threshold
df.loc[mask, 'test'] = 999

print(df.head())

                              date_time  val0  test
date_time                                          
2014-07-01 00:00:00 2014-07-01 00:00:00     7   999
2014-07-01 01:00:00 2014-07-01 01:00:00     4     4
2014-07-01 02:00:00 2014-07-01 02:00:00     8   999
2014-07-01 03:00:00 2014-07-01 03:00:00     5     5
2014-07-01 04:00:00 2014-07-01 04:00:00     7   999
```

Is your question about finding and updating selected values?  Or on getting observations into one-hour buckets?

Comment: hmmm, if use data of OP it is wrong solution. It seems OP need something else.